# arm gcc aarch32 compile longlong constants param why skip r1 register?

Tags: gcc, arm

using toolchains:

```
"gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update"
```

build cmd:

```
"arm-none-eabi-gcc -MMD -g -Wno-discarded-qualifiers -O0 -mcpu=cortex-r52 -c -DGCC -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fp-armv8 -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -falign-functions=16 -falign-jumps=8 -falign-loops=8 -fomit-frame-pointer -funroll-loops printf.c -o printf.o"
```

Found that the code:

```
printf("test hex long number = 0x%lx\n",  0x123456789abcdef0ul);
```

Compiled as:

```
  401372:   a315        add r3, pc, #84 ; (adr r3, 4013c8 <printf_test+0xd8>)
  401374:   e9d3 2300   ldrd    r2, r3, [r3]
  401378:   f245 201c   movw    r0, #21020  ; 0x521c
  40137c:   f2c0 0040   movt    r0, #64 ; 0x40
  401380:   f7ff ff76   bl  401270 <_printf>
```

Why not use "r1" register as params delivery?
That make "_printf" print unexpected.

> test hex long number = 0x9abcdef000000000

How to fix or workaround?
Let "_printf" print as expected "0x123456789abcdef0"

Comment: I don't see how the output `0x9abcdef000000000` is possible with this code, since `%lx` would output a 32-bit value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `r2/r3` is correct.  The [AAPCS ABI](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q3/aapcs32.pdf) specifies that 8-byte objects (or more precisely, objects needing 8-byte alignment) shall be passed in an even/odd register pair.  See Section 6.3 stage C3. This is most likely so that `ldrd/strd` can be used, as they have this same restriction.

The bug in your program is that `0x123456789abcdef0ul` is of type `unsigned long long` despite the `ul` suffix, since it is too large for the 32-bit `unsigned long`.  As such you need to use the `%llx` format specifier with it.  If you do, then `printf` will correctly find the argument in `r2/r3` and everything works fine.

With the code as it is, you ought to get a compiler warning about the format specifier not matching the argument type.

Comment: Because of that my `printf` func is implement locally. Maybe I should find the code deal with `unsigned long long` in libc implement `printf`.

Comment: @shifeng.yuan: libc will just be using the `<stdarg.h>` mechanisms, which should handle this properly.  E.g. if you do `va_arg(v, unsigned long long)` it will get it from the appropriate registers.  That would be the simplest way to do your own printf also.  `<stdarg.h>` is implemented by the compiler, not the library (it's part of a "freestanding implementation") so you can use it even if you are not linking with a libc otherwise.

Comment: @shifeng.yuan: If you're writing a printf in assembly, you will probably find it more useful to read the AAPCS spec than to try to see how `va_arg` is implemented, since that's usually a compiler builtin instead of having ordinary source code.

Comment: I already use the `va_arg(ap, long long)`.  `out_num(va_arg(ap, long long), 16, lead, maxwidth);`  assemble code is `4011ba: 9b02       ldr r3, [sp, #8]` `4011bc: 3307       adds r3, #7` `4011be: f023 0307  bic.w r3, r3, #7` `4011c2: f103 0208  add.w r2, r3, #8` `4011c6: 9202       str r2, [sp, #8]` `4011c8: e9d3 0100  ldrd r0, r1, [r3]` As you said, `va_arg` do the appropriate offset. But, I can't ensure that `[sp, #8]` which is a stack address where r1,r2,r3 saved into is aligned 8-bytes at r2. Such as when r1 at 0x???0, r2 will at 0x???4. r2 is not aligned  8-bytes. The issue will happen.

Comment: @shifeng.yuan: I'm afraid I don't follow.  Can you create a [mcve] including both the varargs function and the function that calls it?  Either edit it into your question above or ask a new one (comments are not convenient for posting code).  Also state what compiler you are using, and with what options.

Comment: @shifeng.yuan: AAPCS requires that the stack be aligned to 8 bytes at a "public interface" (i.e at any function call), see 6.2.1.2.  So your function actually can safely assume that `[sp, #8]` is aligned to 8 bytes on entry to the function.  If not then the calling function, or some other function up the chain, is broken.

Comment: I have raise a new question about this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267716/arm32-gcc-unsigned-long-long-args-passing-how-to-ensure-align8bytes-on-stack. It is so much thanks for your help.