# arm32 gcc 'unsigned long long' args passing how to ensure align8bytes on stack?

Tags: gcc, arm

using toolchains:
"gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update"

build cmd:
"arm-none-eabi-gcc -MMD -g -Wno-discarded-qualifiers -O0 -mcpu=cortex-r52 -c -DGCC -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fp-armv8 -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -falign-functions=16 -falign-jumps=8 -falign-loops=8 -fomit-frame-pointer -funroll-loops printf.c -o printf.o"

C code:

```
int _printf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    my_vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return 0;
}

int printf_test(void) {
    _printf("test hex long number = %d %d 0x%lx\n", 123, 321, 0x123456789abcdef0ull);
    return 0;
}
static void out_num(long long n, int base, char lead, int maxwidth) {
    unsigned long long m = 0;
    char buf[MAX_NUMBER_BYTES], *s = buf + sizeof(buf);
    int count = 0, i = 0;

    *--s = '\0';

    if (n < 0 && base == 10) {
        m = -n;
    } else {
        m = n;
    }

    do {
        *--s = hex_tab[m % base];
        count++;
    } while ((m /= base) != 0);

    if( maxwidth && count < maxwidth) {
        for (i = maxwidth - count; i; i--) {
            *--s = lead;
        }
    }

    if (n < 0 && base == 10) {
        *--s = '-';
    }

    outs(s);
}
```

asm:

```
<printf_test>:
b500        push    {lr}
b083        sub sp, #12
a30a        add r3, pc, #40 ; (adr r3, 4012a0 <printf_test+0x30>)
e9d3 2300   ldrd    r2, r3, [r3]
**e9cd 2300     strd    r2, r3, [sp]**  // save the longlong args into sp
f240 1241   movw    r2, #321    ; 0x141
217b        movs    r1, #123    ; 0x7b
f245 0020   movw    r0, #20512  ; 0x5020
f2c0 0040   movt    r0, #64 ; 0x40
f7ff ffe0   bl  401250 <_printf>
2300        movs    r3, #0
4618        mov r0, r3
b003        add sp, #12
f85d fb04   ldr.w   pc, [sp], #4
bf00        nop
f3af 8000   nop.w
9abcdef0    bls ff338e68 <__bss_end+0xfe3f4ba8>
12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
f3af 8000   nop.w
f3af 8000   nop.w

<_printf>:
b40f        push    {r0, r1, r2, r3}
b500        push    {lr}
b083        sub sp, #12
**ab05          add r3, sp, #20**   // the va_list ap just point to r1 address, the longlong args on sp is missing?
9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
9901        ldr r1, [sp, #4]
9804        ldr r0, [sp, #16]
f7ff fe9f   bl  400fa0 <my_vprintf>
2300        movs    r3, #0
4618        mov r0, r3
b003        add sp, #12
f85d eb04   ldr.w   lr, [sp], #4
b004        add sp, #16
4770        bx  lr
```

when in my_vprintf func, the va_list ap args address is:

```
0x0000000000F439B8  0000007B 00000141 12345678 9ABCDEF0  {...A...xV4.ðÞ¼.
0x0000000000F439C8  12345678 0000000A 004044D1 00000000  xV4.....ÑD@.....
```

the result printf is:

```
test hex long number = 123 321 0x9abcdef012345678
```

expected is:

```
test hex long number = 123 321 0x123456789abcdef0
```

my_vprintf code:

```
static int my_vprintf(const char *fmt, va_list ap) {
    char lead = ' ';
    int alignleft = 0;
    int  maxwidth = 0;

    for(; *fmt != '\0'; fmt++) {
        if (*fmt != '%') {
            outc(*fmt);
            continue;
        }

        lead = ' ';
        maxwidth = 0;

        //format : %08d, %8d,%d,%u,%x,%f,%c,%s
        fmt++;

        if (*fmt == '-') {
            fmt++;
            alignleft = 1;
        }

        if(*fmt == '0') {
            lead = '0';
            fmt++;
        }

        while(*fmt >= '0' && *fmt <= '9') {
            maxwidth *= 10;
            maxwidth += (*fmt - '0');
            fmt++;
        }

        switch (*fmt) {
            case 'd':
                out_num(va_arg(ap, int),          10, lead, maxwidth);
                break;

            case 'o':
                out_num(va_arg(ap, unsigned int),  8, lead, maxwidth);
                break;

            case 'u':
                out_num(va_arg(ap, unsigned int), 10, lead, maxwidth);
                break;

            case 'l':
                fmt++;

                if (*fmt == 'd') {
                    out_num(va_arg(ap, long long), 10, lead, maxwidth);
                } else if (*fmt == 'u') {
                    out_num(va_arg(ap, unsigned long long), 10, lead, maxwidth);
                } else if (*fmt == 'x' || *fmt == 'X') {
                    out_num(va_arg(ap, unsigned long long), 16, lead, maxwidth);
                }

                break;
            case 'f':
                out_float(va_arg(ap, double), maxwidth);
                break;

            case 'X':
            case 'x':
                out_num(va_arg(ap, unsigned int), 16, lead, maxwidth);
                break;

            case 'c':
                outc(va_arg(ap, int));
                break;

            case 's':
                out_str(va_arg(ap, char *), lead, alignleft, maxwidth);
                break;

            default:
                outc(*fmt);
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the longlong passing args on stack couldn't complie as expected and deal with appropriately. Why it happened?

Comment: ul is 32 bit ull is 64 bit, you passed it as a 32 bit expecting 64?  if you remove the _ and let the compiler see the printf you get the warning right?

Comment: This needs a [mcve]; we need to see the entire source of `my_vprintf` (removing code that's not relevant, but leaving a working and compilable full program).  But `my_printf` seems to be written in a confusing way.  It looks like you are using `%lu` or `%lx` to print an argument of type `unsigned long long`.  But with standard printf, `%lu` and `%lx` are for `unsigned long`, and the format specifiers for `unsigned long long` are `%llu` and `%llx`.

Comment: You've also made the code more confusing by writing `0x123456789abcdef0ul` with a `ul` suffix, as if it were `unsigned long`, but it is actually an `unsigned long long` by the rules of C numeric constants.  Why not say what you mean, and write `0x123456789abcdef0ull`?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Using `%lu` or `%lx` to print `long long` is what I want to do. Change `0x123456789abcdef0ul` to `0x123456789abcdef0ull` have no different in my result. The full my_vprintf is attached. `out_num` function just output the first arg so I think it is not nessaray.

Comment: I think we do need to see `out_num`, because it appears to be a function to which you pass `int`, `unsigned`, `long long` and `unsigned long long`.  So what is the type of its first argument?  There isn't any standard type that can represent all the values of all those types.

Comment: The reason for asking for a [mcve] is not just to read more code, but so that we can understand the program's behavior **by testing it**.

Comment: `out_num` first argument is `long long` as attached code. Sorry for unfamiliar with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that I don't know how to do that on paticular gcc toolchain for a C code.

Comment: "the va_list ap just point to r1 address, the longlong args on sp is missing?" The longlong args on the stack are still on the stack, right after r3. The problem appears to be in the use of `va_arg()`. The codegen for `va_arg(ap, unsigned long long)` isn't present, but it should be rounding up to the next multiple of 8. Maybe your stack is unaligned? You can step through the asm when you get to the `va_arg(ap, unsigned long long)` to see where it's loading the value from.

Comment: To make a MRE: Start with the program you have, which you can compile and run and reproduce the bug.  Start removing (or stubbing out) parts of it that are not relevant, making sure every time that it still compiles and runs and shows the bug.  When you can't remove any more, it is minimal.